# Stream video through socket to html5 video tag

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, media-source

Hello i`ve been trying to stream a webm video through a socket.io socket directly to the html5 video tag. The client and server code follows below:

Server:

```
(function() {
    var Alert, Channel, Receiver, Takeover, express, pathLib;

    pathLib = require("path");
    fs = require("fs");
    express = require("express");

    module.exports = function(app, sockets) {
        router = express.Router();

        router.get("/clearAlerts", function(req, res) {
            console.log("reached!");
            return sockets.emit("alert-deleted");
        });

        router.get("/castVideo", function(req, res) {
            //move this to a better place
            console.log("reachedCastVideoss");
            var readStream = fs.createReadStream(pathLib.join(__dirname + "/../../../public/elephants-dream.webm"));
            readStream.addListener('data', function(data) {
                console.log("cast-video emitted");
                sockets.emit('cast-video', data);
            });
        });

        return app.use('/custom/', router);
    };

}).call(this);
```

Client:

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4994');


window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
window.MediaSource = window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource;

var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
var video = document.getElementById("video");
var queue = [];
var sourceBuffer;
var firstChunk = true;

video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

streamIt = function(e) {
    video.pause();
    mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');
    mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].addEventListener('updateend', onBufferUpdated);

    socket.on("cast-video", function(data) {
        console.log("appending to buffer");
        var uIntArray = new Uint8Array(data);

        if (firstChunk) {
            mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].appendBuffer(uIntArray);
            firstChunk = false;
        }

        queue.push(uIntArray);
        if (queue.length === 33) {
            //mediaSource.endOfStream();
        }
    });

    var onBufferUpdated = function() {
        if (queue.length) {
            mediaSource.sourceBuffers[0].appendBuffer(queue.shift());
        }
    };
};


mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', streamIt);
mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', streamIt);
```

When I try to run this code, It seems that the first chunk of the stream is appended
to the sourceBuffer, I can see the first frame(title and an url) of the video file im trying to play, but thats it. It seems that only the first call appendBuffer works. I read somewhere something about a required initialization segment for the video to play, but I also saw an working example that does not use this initialization segment, so im a little confuse.([link to the example](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html))
Can anyone clarify if I really need this initial segment? If I do, how can I retrieve the byte range of this segment? Or if I dont need this segment, what is wrong in my code? Thank you.

Trying a little bit more today,Ive found that if I use the same file from http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html, this code actually works. When I try with the files from 
http://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files, the code does not works. I have no idea why.

Comment: Try going to `chrome://media-internals/` while trying to load the video to get some more information on what might be going on.  It's likely that your video doesn't have the right keyframes.  Running it through these tools might help: https://github.com/acolwell/mse-tools

Comment: Thanks Adam, I will take a look on those resources you mentioned. I could manage to make it work though and its probably what you said about the keyframes. I have re-generated the the .webm video with ffmpeg, and now the same code works for the new .webm video.