# MediaSource appending to SourceBuffer does not work after the first time

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, stream, socket.io

I am currently trying to stream a .webm video file via socket.io to my client (currently using Chrome as client).

Appending the first `Uint8Array` to the SourceBuffer works fine but appending further ones does not work and throws the following error: 
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null.`

My current code:

```
'use strict';

let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
let video = document.getElementById("player");
let queue = [];
let sourceBuffer;

video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
    sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');

    socket.on("video", function(data) {
        let uIntArray = new Uint8Array(data);

        if (!sourceBuffer.updating) {
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(uIntArray);
        } else {
            queue.push(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Server side code (snippet)

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
            console.log("Client connected");

            let readStream = fs.createReadStream("bunny.webm");
            readStream.addListener('data', function(data) {
                socket.emit('video', data);
            });
        });
```

I also removed the webkit checks since this will only run on Chromium browsers.

Comment: Can you post your server code as well? It'll make it easier to set up and test

Comment: sure, I thought the server code is unnecessary as it looked like a client error for me but you are right it could help.

Comment: No errors on my end. It might be a problem with the file itself. Since you are using a "bunny.webm" file and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309027/stream-video-through-socket-to-html5-video-tag) has a similar problem with files downloaded from http://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files ...did you already try re-formatting the file or another file?

Comment: Yeah, tried it few. But great to hear that. I will try some different files later.

Comment: Could you send me the file you are using? I am only getting the first frame / chunk of the video and afterwards the `Failed to appendBuffer` error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Actually not. Sorry.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue ?

Comment: No, but I didn't really continue working on this. I was waiting for some method that would replace `appendBuffer` but I can't recall the same and I think it never got implemented. I had a small-ish version, which could stream a special encoding for up to 30 seconds in low quality or something like this, so a rather non practical version. And since I had no real use for it any longer, I stopped working on it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to free the buffer, see the remove() function
http://w3c.github.io/media-source/#widl-SourceBuffer-remove-void-double-start-unrestricted-double-end

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: I tried to call this method after the first appendBuffer but I am getting the `InvalidAccessError` error because `mediaSource.duration` is `NaN` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/remove

Comment: I think you may have to set this duration yourself : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/duration

Comment: When should I call the remove? I called it via the console but still couldn't add a new chunk.

Comment: can you get the timestamps of the first chunk ? basically I would take those timestamps, deduce and set the media duration then call remove(start,end);  after each socketio event

Comment: Do you mean the UNIX timestamp? And calling remove would remove the video out of the player so this would make the video unplayable in the end. Remove works with the duration and not timestamps. (I am probably getting you wrong, sorry)

Comment: Dumb question , is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer/appendStream not more fitting your need here ?

Comment: Pretty clever question actually. Would fit well, yes. I will rewrite the server part later to use socket.io-stream because as far as I know there are know  `ReadableStream `'s in socket.io, are there?

Comment: it seems that some modules exists : https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream

Comment: Yeah I know that module but that would require me to rewrite some code parts since I can no longer use vanilla socket.io. But this will probably work. Will try later

Comment: Sadly the `appendStream` method is not implemented in (most) browsers. (Using newest Chrome)